# Why does the Laplace transform shift theorem not work with a positive shift?

Tags: calculus, integration, laplace-transform

I am trying to compute the integral

$$ I = \int\limits_1^\infty e^{-t x} \sqrt{t} J_1\!\left(2 \sqrt{t}\right) \mathrm{d} t $$

which I encountered in my research. Now, I noticed that it has the same form as the Laplace transform, if only that lower integration limit were 0 instead of 1. I thought I could apply the shift theorem:

$$ f\!\left(t\right) = \sqrt{t} J_1\!\left(2 \sqrt{t}\right) $$

$$ I = \int\limits_1^\infty e^{-t x} f\!\left(t\right) \Theta\!\left(t\right) \mathrm{d} t = e^{-x} \int\limits_0^\infty e^{-t x} f\!\left(t + 1\right) \Theta\!\left(t + 1\right) \mathrm{d} t $$

My logic is that, in the first integral, since $t > 0$ always, it doesn't matter if we insert the Heaviside theta function; the second step is just a linear change of variables.

As far as I can tell, this is the right form for the Laplace transform of a shifted function *except* that the shift $a$ is supposed to satisfy $a > 0$ where $f\!\left(t - a\right)$ is the shifted function. Numerically, if I choose a value for $x$, I can do this integral, and the formula above holds:

```
(* the target function *)
f[t_] := Sqrt[t] BesselJ[1, 2 Sqrt[t]]

(* the original integral *)
With[{x = 1}, 
 NIntegrate[Exp[-t x] f[t], {t, 1, Infinity}, AccuracyGoal -> 5]]

(* the shifted integral *)
With[{x = 1}, 
 Exp[-x] NIntegrate[
   Exp[-t x] f[t + 1] HeavisideTheta[t + 1], {t, 0, Infinity}, 
   AccuracyGoal -> 5]]

>> 0.175032
>> 0.175032
```

However, the Laplace transform of $f\!\left(t\right)$ is given by

$$ F\!\left(x\right) = \frac{e^{-1/x}}{x^2} $$

and [the Wikipedia table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems) says that

$$ \mathcal{L}\!\left[f\!\left(t - a\right) \Theta\!\left(t - a\right)\right] = e^{-a x} F\!\left(x\right) $$

The factors of $e^{-x}$ and $e^x$ cancel, and I'm left with

```
With[{x = 1}, Exp[-1/x] / x^2 // N]

>> 0.135335
```

I get a different answer. I suspect this all has something to do with my shift being positive, but I don't understand conceptually why that should be a problem, since I never assumed $a > 0$ explicitly. I appreciate any help solving this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Laplace transform of $t \mapsto u(t-c) f(t)$ for $c>0$ has no simple relationship with that of $f$, intuitively because some of the information about $f$ on $[0,\infty)$ has been destroyed. The shift theorem applies to $u(t-c) f(t-c)$.

Comment: Does this apply even though I was able to write my integrand in that form, though? Because my last expression for $I$ does have $u\!\left(t - c\right) f\!\left(t - c\right)$ in the integral.

Comment: @emprice Yes, but with $c<0$. When $c>0$ you just move all the information about $f$ to the right and so when you change variables you just pick up a factor from the exponential. When $c<0$ you move some of the information about $f$ into $(-\infty,0)$ so that it gets ignored in the integration. This is why they're not related in any simple way.

Answer (score 0):

*Just for the integral of your interest.*

$$I = \int\limits_1^\infty e^{-t x} \sqrt{t}\, J_1\!\left(2 \sqrt{t}\right) \,dt=\int\limits_0^\infty e^{-t x} \sqrt{t}\, J_1\!\left(2 \sqrt{t}\right) \,dt-\int\limits_0^1 e^{-t x} \sqrt{t}\, J_1\!\left(2 \sqrt{t}\right) \,dt$$
As you wrote, assuming $x >0$,
$$\int\limits_0^\infty e^{-t x} \sqrt{t}\, J_1\!\left(2 \sqrt{t}\right) \,dt=\frac{e^{-1/x}}{x^2}$$ Now, for the second integral, use
$$\sqrt{t}\, J_1\!\left(2 \sqrt{t}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\frac {t^n}{n! \,(n-1)! }$$ which makes
$$\int\limits_0^1 e^{-t x} \sqrt{t}\, J_1\!\left(2 \sqrt{t}\right) \,dt=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{\Gamma (n+1,x)-\Gamma (n+1,0)}{n!\,(n-1)! }\, x^{-(n+1)}$$  For $x=1$, the partial sums (from $n=1$ to $n=p$) converge extremely fast
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 p & \sum_{n=1}^p \\
 1 & 0.2642411177 \\
 2 & 0.1839397206 \\
 3 & 0.1934337990 \\
 4 & 0.1928238246 \\
 5 & 0.1928485823 \\
 6 & 0.1928478886 \\
 7 & 0.1928479028 \\
 8 & 0.1928479026 
\end{array}
\right)$$